# how to set a PHP variable if nothing has been posted to it yet?

Tags: php, variables

I have a PHP graphs page that displays graphs generated from another PHP file.

This graph generating PHP file will have its variables changed through an AJAX script.

When the PHP graphs page first loads i need to be able to identify whether a variable in the generating PHP file is empty so i can change it to a default value until data overwrites it through the $_get function.

I have tried this so far with no luck and am a bit stuck, any assistance would be greatly appreciated as i am very new to PHP. thanks :)

```
$course = $_GET['usercourse'];

if (empty($course))
{
    $course = 'All';
}

else
{
}
```

Comment: `$course = isset($_GET['usercourse']) ? $_GET['usercourse'] : "All";`

Comment: @SalmanA You should post that as an answer, especially since it's the best thing written on this question so far.  (It's depressing how much misinformation has been answered on this question...)

Comment: Notices aside, the posted code should work unless you want to distinguish between `usercourse` being passed as empty string or 0 and not being passed at all. What doesn't work for you?

Comment: @SalmanA got it all working thanks to you

Answer (score 3):

Use the **[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)** function.

```
if (isset($_GET['usercourse'])
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `isset` be the same as `empty` in this case?

Comment: @woz php is odd language. it have `isset`, `empty` and `is_null` function that basically do the same thing, but are different.

Comment: No, empty isn't the same in this context (assuming you both mean `!empty()`).  Imagine `$_GET['usercourse'] === '0'`: `(!empty($_GET['usercourse'])) === false`, but `isset($_GET['usercourse']) === true`

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)** function.

```
if (isset($_GET['usercourse'])
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This could use some clarification.  If $course were only defined inside of the first if, this could issue a notice for an undefined variable.

Comment: Still wrong.  What happens if `$_GET['usercourse']` isn't defined?  You'll get an undefined index warning.

Comment: @Corbin so better to use `isset`

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset` function, like this,

```
if(isset($_GET['usercourse']))
$course = $_GET['usercourse'];

if (empty($course))
{
$course = 'All';
} else {
 //do something...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Naive code example that checks if the variable was set and it is not equal to empty string:

```
$course = isset($_GET['usercourse']) && $_GET['usercourse'] !== ''
    ? $_GET['usercourse']
    : 'All';
```

Slightly better:

```
$course = isset($_GET['usercourse']) && preg_match('@^(LIST|of|AccEPtabLE|vaLUes)$@i', $_GET['usercourse'])
    ? $_GET['usercourse']
    : 'All';

$course = isset($_GET['usercourse']) && in_array($_GET['usercourse'], array('list', 'of', 'acceptable', 'values'))
    ? $_GET['usercourse']
    : 'All';
```

Even better:

Use [Filter Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php).

Comment: If he's going to check against a delineated white list, it would make more sense to have an array of $allowed = ...; and then check in_array instead.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have answered your direct question, but I think there's something deeper here that should be explained.

You typically want to avoid accessing array indexes that you are not certain exist.

For example:

```
$a = array('foo' => 'bar');
echo $a['test']; //bad!
```

The same applies for $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, etc.  Don't access indexes unless you know that they exist.

**Note that for user defined indexes, this translates to "don't access indexes unless you've checked that they exist."**

```
$content = $_GET['content']; //ALWAYS wrong
```

You have three options for checking array indexes: isset, empty, and array_key_exists.

`isset($x)` returns true iff $x is non-null.  `isset` is essentially equivalent to: `$x !== null`, except isset will not issue undefined index/variable notices.

`(empty($x) === (!isset($x) || !$x))`

In other words, empty consider anything loosely equal to false to be empty.  This is useful in certain situations.

`array_key_exists($key, $array)` is a simple guarantee that `$array[$key]` will not issue an undefined index notice.

So what's the easiest way to extract user input in a proper manner?

```
$content = (isset($_GET['content'])) ? $_GET['content'] : null;
```

You have an imporant guarantee at this point in that `$content !== null` iff the user provided input.

---

Note that you should also avoid ever having an excecution path that leaves a variable undefined:

```
if (isset($_GET['content'])) {
    $content = $_GET['content'];
}

echo $content; //WRONG - $content is not guaranteed to be defined
```

You could use $content in that situation if it were wrapped in isset or empty, but that hampers the readability of code.  If you want to leave a variable undefined under some condition, define it as null.  That leaves it as 'undefined' without it issuing variable doesn't exist warnings.

```
$a = null;
var_dump($a === $b); //true, because the non-existent $b is treated as false
//(note that this is terrible style though -- this would issue a variable doesn't exist warning for $b
```

---

There's also, of course, PHP's [filter](http://php.net/filter) extension.  In particular, you can use [filter_input](http://php.net/filter_input) to avoid rewriting a lot of the code for handling user input.

You can read more about proper (or, paranoid, as some may call it) input handling [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12757/basic-user-registration-code-in-php/12769#12769) or [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12647/php-dynamic-insert-mysql-is-there-a-better-way-than-this/12649#12649) in the proper sections.

---

As an aside, you should always develop with errors cranked all the way up, and you should be monitoring for any kind of error (warning, notice, etc).  This will help prevent potential logical bugs, and it tends to keep code clean.  (There seems to be a correlation between code that never issues notices and well written code.)

Comment: Excellent answer - not only answers the question but gives a proper explanation of all the factors involved.

Answer (score 0):

why not compare against an empty string?

```
if (!isset($course) || empty($course) ) {
    $course = 'All';
}
```

Comment: `empty()` would return true for an empty string, thus making the OR condition totally redundant.